# Gimp command-line

Tags: command-line, python, gimp

I am using GIMP 2.8 and Windows 10. I want to run a python script for GIMP via command-line. I read a similar question under

https: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001226/how-to-execute-python-fu-script-from-shell-via-gimp

and the answer was

gimp  -n --no-interface --batch "(python-fu-gradient-save-as-css  RUN-NONINTERACTIVE \"Sunrise\" \"/tmp/grad.css\")" --batch "(gimp-quit 1)"

but to be honest I am not able to understand it. My script is under C:\Programme\GIMP 2\bin\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\uliW1.py. Does anyone know what I must write in the command-line?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560)?

Comment: `sys.path.append('C:\\Programme\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp\\2.0\\plug-ins');import uliW1` as suggested in [this @geekobi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42874499/3439404).